# Is it possible to map a column type to another Object attribute class?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping

I have columns in some tables that are int/integer, where 0=false and 1=true, Can I map this to a boolean Object attribute?

Something like:

```
   public class...
   //instead of 
   private int playeble;
   //something like
   @AwesomAnnotationConvertion(....)
   private boolean playeble;
```

I'm using Hibenate, but we are going to migrate to EclipseLink so I would prefer a standard implementation if it does exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`@Convert`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Convert.html) and [`@Converter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Converter.html):

```
public class YourEntity {
    @Convert(converter=BooleanOneZeroConverter.class)
    private Boolean playable;
}

@Converter
public class BooleanOneZeroConverter implements AttributeConverter<Boolean, Integer> {
    private static final Integer TRUE_VALUE = 1;
    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(Boolean value) {
        //1 is true, 0 is false
        return Boolean.TRUE.equals(value) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    @Override
    public Boolean convertToEntityAttribute(Integer value) {
        return TRUE_VALUE.equals(value);
    }
}
```

Note that code above applies for JPA 2.1.